# Email Ticketing System Suggestions

Tags: php, email

I'm about to start a PHP application that will basically accomplish the following:

- People email support@example.com
- The system creates a 'ticket'
- Users can either respond to that email to post a reply (system automatically adds to the ticket and emails the originating emailer).
- Repeat steps 1 and 2 until the ticket is updated to resolved in the system.

I haven't really worked on the email side of PHP. Does anyone have any suggestions? (Articles, tutorials, resources, etc) that would point me in the right direction on how to tell if the email is part of a chain, not to include previous responses when adding it to the ticket, removing the signature... stuff like that.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm currently working on this and I'm trying to come up with a solution for email signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use some existing system, unless you're building it for the exercise.
If you're planning on actually using this system, go with something pre-existing instead. Options include:

- [RT](http://www.bestpractical.com/rt)
- [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/)
- [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org) (does only support reporting via email, comments have to be entered on the web)
- And probably MANY more

As for working with Email in PHP, my suggestion would be to see how far you get with [Zend_Mail](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html).
You can also work with raw imap, using the [Imap extension for php](http://php.net/imap), part of the standard install. How you discover "threads" and remove signatures will be the same as in any other programming language, I assume.

Two other libraries I've used in the past for sending mails (not reading) are [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: This is going to be heavily expanded in a few months to allow for a lot more features, so I'd like to explore developing it myself. RT seems like the best option out of that bunch, thanks.

Comment: But RT is not PHP. I need a PHP suggestion especially if I'm going with a premade solution that I'll be building off of later. Really looking for something closer to my original question of how to handle emails with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the updated PHP suggestions.

Comment: If I were you I think I'd put more of the responsibility of the mail routing on the MTA though. For qmail for example, have a look at http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#extension-addresses. You can have the different issues go to different recepients, like support-issue77772@example.com, and will all get delivered to support@example.com.

Comment: @gnud We're using Exchange right now. Is there any way to either do it with exchange or to do it without switching everyone off exchange?

Comment: I was only talking about the receiving mailbox that the system will be using, not whatever mail solution the users are currently using. Are you planning to have the system use an exchange mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe an email to a PHP script. I'm not sure what you're using, but CPanel, for example, allows you to pipe the entire contents of the email to a script where you conduct further processing.

Then you could take the original subject, add an [id] to that subject and use that as your unique reference for all replies.

Also take a look at - [Process incoming e-mail messages using PHP](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/2/post/1-Process-incoming-email-messages-using-PHP.html).

Comment: I'm on an IIS server, and the exchange email is hosted on another network. It will need to go through POP/IMAP. I'll check out that link, thank you!